# Are the Javascript and Java Image objects compatible?

Tags: javascript, java

Sorry if this is a newbie question but if I create and image object in Javascript and send it to a Java applet with an Image argument, will the types still match? A quick example would be

```
 var image = new image();
 image.src = "pic.gif";
 app.example(image);
```

for the Javascript, and

```
public void example(Image n){
}
```

for the Java code. If they aren't compatible, would the File object be?

Comment: It’s an `Image` object, not an `image` object. `Image` creates an `HTMLImageElement`.

Comment: Sigh... if only it were, how much easier web programming would be :P

Comment: What API's or libraries are you using to talk between your Java and your Javascript code? The types will never "just" match unless you're talking in a format that is native to both sides, and your API supports sending.

Comment: I kinda figured as much. Is there a way to send Images or Files to the applet then?

Comment: Your best bet would be to serialize your Image/File into an array of bytes (which both Javascript (ArrayBuffer) and Java (FileInputStream) have names for) and you might be able to find an API that can talk byte arrays between the two languages.

Comment: Perhaps if you could tell us why you want to do this, there might be a way around the problem. See [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: @kevinJohnson I'm using JQuery, JQuery-ui and Spring. Sorry about that, I'm trying to create a TrayIcon in the SystemTray from a signed jar applet in my webapp. The code to create the TrayIcon has to be called from Javascript. My main problem is the image for the TrayIcon. If I use an absolute path for the image in my applet, the whole thing works great but using a relative path doesn't work so now I'm trying to grab the image in Javascript and pass it to the applet.

Comment: Why can't you use an absolute path for the image? I assume the image stays constant in your application. It's been a while since I've used Java, but I think you can include your image as a resource in your .jar and reference it from there.

Comment: Because the absolute path isn't staying constant. Actually when I tested the Java file it worked when I added the image to my project and used `.getResource()` but the doesn't when I create the jar. I extracted it but the image wasn't there. Would I have to modify my build.xml?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85363/discussion-between-kevin-johnson-and-get-otter-here).